# Certain shadows don't appear while playing in BGE

Tags: game-engine, shadows

I can't get certain shadows to show in BGE. I have the correct lighting with the sun and hemi lamps. 
[image: hemi lamp][image: sun lamp]
When I'm editing in BGE, all the shadows show like I want. 
[image: Editing]
But when I press p to play, all shadows still work except for one. The one that doesn't show while playing is a bunch of planes connected together, all of them with the same texture on it to make a clump of grass. 
[image: Playing]
When I was making it on a different layer with the same lamps, the shadow it casted worked while editing and while playing. But when I moved it to a different layer with the same lamps, the shadows only worked when editing and not when I press p to play. I have no idea why. I'm using GLSL if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

you need adjust this settings to correct the shadows projection in the bge 
and this apply in bge, blender render and cycles
[image: adjust this control of shadow]
[image: Blender Render]
[image: BGE]
[image: Play game BGE Properties]
[image: Before play]

Comment: @GarrisonManson check the las images inside de answer, is very easy and very clear to understand.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, but when I was looking at your pictures I realized that when transparency is on, the shadows don't show. I turned it off, and the shadows showed up. However, the grass you saw in my pictures are a texture printed on to multiple planes. When transparency was turned off, the planes became visible, which I don't want. Is there a way to make the shadow of the texture show and the planes not show?

Comment: I figured it out! The shadows were there all along. Your instructions were right. It was the size of the shadow that I had to fix. When I turned it to the max, the shadows showed up like I wanted. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: @GarrisonManson vote up my answer